# How can I filter out the internal Dynaconf settings?

Tags: python, configuration

```
from .config import settings
for k,v in settings.items():
  print(k,v)
```

this prints things like `RENAMED_VARS`, `SETTINGS_MODULE`, `PROJECT_ROOT`, `*_FOR_DYNACONF` in addition to the configuration parameter that I explicitly setup in my `settings.toml`

Is there anyway to just get the configuration parameters that I defined excluding the ones that dynaconf creates by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only for reading the values you can use `.as_dict()` like this:

```
from .config import settings

for k,v in setting.as_dict().items():
```

the `as_dict()` is by default `as_dict(internal=False)` so the dict won't have any of the internal parameters,

Answer (score 0):

On my side I use default_settings.toml for the default and load it first and use settings for personal related items that could be one option. So for your case you could just call the settings.toml.

```
import os
from dynaconf import Dynaconf

ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

settings = Dynaconf(
    root_path=os.path.dirname(ROOT),
    settings_files=[
        os.path.join(ROOT, "default_settings.toml"),
        'settings.toml',
        '.secrets.toml'
    ],
    load_dotenv=True,
    environments=True,
    default_env="default",
)
```